# Rstudio Support for S4 Method Auto-completion

Tags: r, autocomplete, rstudio, r-s4

I'm attempting to see if it is possible for Rstudio to autocomplete S4 method parameters for a generic I own.  An [Rstudio blogpost](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205273297-Code-Completion) suggests this might be possible, but trying it on methods in my [diffobj](https://github.com/brodieG/diffobj) package does not appear to work, e.g.:

```
library(diffobj)
diffPrint('hello', 'world', for...
```

where `for...` denotes me starting to type one of the parameters for the `c('ANY', 'ANY')` method to the generic (i.e. the default one) only gives me the generic parameters.  The generic only has three parameters: `target`, `current`, and `...`.  The methods have lots of parameters that are matched to the `...` in the generic.

So, should I expect this to work?  Are there known working S4 examples I could look at to figure out what's different for them, or even better, specific instructions of how to get this to work?

**UPDATE**: This is now reported as an [Rstudio bug](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7851)

Comment: It doesn't work in base R code completion:  see `utils:::functionArgs` which says `warning("cannot handle S4 methods yet")`.  I think RStudio does its own completion, and that blog posting (originally from 2015) suggests it should work, but it doesn't work for me on your example or using the `chol()` generic from the `Matrix` package.